Use nltk additional data in Foundry Code Repository
I need to work with nltk Additional Data, such as  corpora, toy grammars, trained models.
nltk suggests to use the interactive installer embedded in the package, but this is not compatible with Palantir Foundry Code Repository environments, i.e., it is not feasible to script
import nltk
nltk.download()


In order to be able to use external data for nltk, it is possible to add a specific library in the Libraries menu, called nltk_data.
To do so, be sure that your repository is configured with external-conda-forge in the Backing Artifacts repositories section of your repository Settings
Then proceed to look for the package nltk_data in the Libraries, as such:

